# Linear autonomous systems in the plane: direction of the rotation conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
$$ \begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = ax+by \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = cx+dy
\end {cases}$$

If $$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}$$
has complex eigenvalues, then the phase portrait are spirals. 
If $c>0$, the rotation is counter-clockwise, if $c<0$ it's clockwise. Also, if $b>0$, the rotation is clockwise, if $b<0$ it's counter-clockwise.

How to show that these conditions are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of the coefficient matrix is
$(a-d)^2 + 4 b c$.  The eigenvalues are non-real if and only if the discriminant is negative, and that requires $b c < 0$.  Thus $b > 0$ if and only if $c < 0$, and $b < 0$ if and only if $c > 0$.